# Asterisk Crash * glibc detected * /usr/sbin/asterisk: malloc(): memory corruptio

Tags: centos, asterisk, sip, ss7

I am using `Asterisk 11.19.0` under production server. Asterisk getting crashed manytimes a day. I am  getting below message.

> *** glibc detected *** /usr/sbin/asterisk: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x00007f2d6c0016f0 ***
>   ======= Backtrace: =========                                                                   /lib64/libc.so.6[0x3c49075f3e]
>   /lib64/libc.so.6[0x3c4907a4fa]
>   /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_calloc+0xcd)[0x3c4907a8cd]
>   /usr/sbin/asterisk(ast_frdup+0xc7)[0x4dfce7]
>   /usr/sbin/asterisk[0x4709cf]
>   /usr/sbin/asterisk(ast_answer+0x324)[0x488d44]
>   /usr/lib/asterisk/modules/res_agi.so(+0x939b)[0x7f2f04f9a39b]
>   /usr/lib/asterisk/modules/res_agi.so(+0xb4c4)[0x7f2f04f9c4c4]
>   /usr/lib/asterisk/modules/res_agi.so(+0xbc24)[0x7f2f04f9cc24]
>   /usr/lib/asterisk/modules/res_agi.so(+0xd8d5)[0x7f2f04f9e8d5]
>   /usr/sbin/asterisk(pbx_exec+0x124)[0x520d74]
>   /usr/sbin/asterisk[0x52e689]
>   /usr/sbin/asterisk[0x532ac5]
>   /usr/sbin/asterisk[0x5342cb]
>   /usr/sbin/asterisk[0x5765ab]
>   /lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x3c49407aa1]
>   /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x3c490e8aad]

Answer (score 1):

This info can't help you.

You have use gdb and core dump file.

For more info please consult https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Getting+a+Backtrace